# Not able to get Authorization from incoming request, even we sending it through Postman

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am sending simple `GET` request to backend `API`, that is built in python.
I tried to get the headers from incoming request but not able to get it.
 Here is how I am trying to get it 
`from flask import request
 request.headers.get('Authorization')` 
but every time it return `None` only.

Note: I am able to get all other headers like `request.headers.get("Content-Type")`

Comment: Which server you are using.?

Comment: What you're doing should work: https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/

Comment: Are you setting the Authorization header when making the request?

Comment: @DroidX86 yes I am setting Authorization header while making request, I am not sure why only authorization header is blocked.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Apache server I am using

Answer (score -1):

Am using requests approach which is the best.

see documentation
[links](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

First, You will need to Install and import requests via

```
pip install requests
```

You can see how I set authorization  username and password variable to `auth()` so replace user and pass with your 
authorisation username and password. it it will work.

This code is an illustrations but it works

```
import json
import requests

resp1 = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'),  headers={
                       "Content-Type":"application/json",
                       "Accept": "application/json"
                      })



print('success')
print (resp1.status_code)
print (resp1.headers['content-type'])


#output any other response
content = json.loads(resp1.content)
print(content)
```